# NoTemplateError Backbone.Marrionette but show template in error msg

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

Here is my error:

```
Uncaught NoTemplateError: Could not find template: '<!-- HTML Template --> 
<div id="start_div">

<h2>Choose your path to ... // the rest of the template
```

It is telling me that there is no template but then it outputs the template that it said it could not find.

Here is my code:

```
require(["jquery", "marionette", "views/StartView" ],
function($, marionette, StartView) {

  var SCApp = new marionette.Application();

  SCApp.addRegions({
      mainRegion: "#center_court"
  });
  var startView = new StartView();
  SCApp.mainRegion.show(startView);
  SCApp.start();

}
```

Here is the StartView.js

```
define(["jquery", "marionette", "text!templates/startDiv.html"],

function($, marionette, template){

    var StartView = marionette.ItemView.extend({
       //template: "#start_div"
        template: template
    });

    // Returns the View class
    return StartView;

});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Do I need something for templating in the require method?

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: (For others) In my case the error was happening because an empty template was being loaded. When I added an HTML comment or an empty span into the template, the error went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Marionette search for a template inside the DOM with an ID equal to the one you reference in your view, so you have to change the loadTemplate from Marionette.TemplateCache in this way:

```
Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function(templateId) {

    var template = templateId;

    if (!template || template.length === 0){
        var msg = "Could not find template: '" + templateId + "'";
        var err = new Error(msg);
        err.name = "NoTemplateError";
        throw err;
    }

    return template;
};
```

I actually don't remember where I found this function, I can't find it anymore in Marionette's Wiki, anyway it's working fine for me.

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks!  I looked up the doc once you mentioned it: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and found the next interesting facts:

1. When I've changed the 'not found' template's content, it wasn't changed in error message.
2. When I've changed it's file name (and updated it in import statement) — the error was fixed, updated content was shown.
3. ... then I've changed the name back, everything was fine.

Looks like some bug with caching.

Upd: here I found deep analysis and solution:

http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2014/03/caching-and-cache-busting-with-requirejs.html